# How can I define self.included in a module so that it passes through its included/extended module to subsequent include/extends

Tags: ruby

I have a number of modules that when they are included I want them to call an 'included' function.. this function would be the same for all of them.. I'd like to be able to therefore have this included function in a module and have all these sub modules include that.. This is a contrived example but I need something like....

```
module Humanable
  def self.extended(klass)
    klass.instance_eval do
      define_method :included do |base|
        puts 'I was just included into the Person Class'
      end
    end
  end
end

module Personable
  extend Human
end

class Person
  include Personable
end
```

Where when Person includes Personable..it puts the string from the Humanable module..  This doesn't work but hopefully you get the idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: You say "all submodules *including* it" in your title, but then in your example you *extend* it. Which do you mean?

Comment: I tried to clarify.. forgive the confusion didn't know how to word it.. the example probably is best where I want the include of Personable inside Person to execute the puts 'I was just included' line...  but not have that line execute when Personable extends Human.

Comment: Figured out the answer to what I needed.. thanks for the help Andrew

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you should either post your answer below, which you can accept after 48 hours, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely. You should *not* simply edit your question with the solution.

Comment: I thought I couldn't answer it for 48 hours .. didn't realize I could but just couldn't accept it.. will do that.. thanks.

Comment: Yup, it's [officially encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and you can even add your own answer right on the "Ask Question" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be:

```
module Humanable
  def self.extended(klass)
    klass.define_singleton_method :included do |base|
      puts 'hello'
    end
  end
end

module Personable
  extend Humanable # does **not** puts 'hello'
end

class Person
  include Personable # puts 'hello'
end
```